# Access Product details in JSON format

Tags: product

I am trying to access the details of product in JSON format. 
I need to store details in JSON file as I am going to use this JSON file.
Following is my code.

```
Mage::app('default');
$productId = 35;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
echo json_encode($product);
var_dump(json_decode($product));
exit;
```

But following result is displayed

```
{}NULL
```

Please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forgot to add `getData()` when you are using product obj

use like below it is working  from my end

```
$productId = 35;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
echo json_encode($product->getData());
var_dump(json_decode($product));
exit;
```

hope this will sure solve your issue